# Pointer to a pointer of a character pointer, or why can't I reassign this array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having a lot of trouble performing a very basic task: resizing an array. Every intro to programming class I've ever taken taught me to do this by creating a larger array, filling it, and then point the original array to the new (larger) one.

The program below tokenizes a string into a program name and its argv[] (it's ultimately going to be a basic shell implementation). It allocates space for 8 arguments at a time -- if there are more than 8 then it recursively allocates a larger array and fills it.

Everything is working well (please let me know otherwise!) except I can't point the args array to the moreArgs array. I have a statement that should do this at the end of the getArgs function but it simply is not reassigning the address of args[]. What am I doing wrong?

```
#define debug 1

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char ** getArgs( char *input,  char **args, int ct);

/*Is there a better way than making these global?*/
char ** args;
char **moreArgs;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char input[]="echo arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8 arg9 arg10";
  char inputcpy[strlen(input)];
  strcpy(inputcpy, input);
  char * temp;
  temp=strtok(input, " ");
  char * prog=temp;

  args=( char **) calloc(8, sizeof( char*));  

  getArgs(inputcpy, args, 1);

  if(debug) {
    printf("arg address after: %p\n", args);
    printf("morearg address after func: %p\n", moreArgs);
  }

  /*This is basically  what the shell will look like. The actual implementation will use stdin
   for input. (Unless a pipe or < is present in the input)*/
  int q;
  int pid=fork();
  if (pid!=0) {
    execvp(prog, args); //when moreArgs!=null, args should point to moreArgs
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    int status=0;
    wait(&status);
  }
}


/*This function should takes the first argument and inserts int into the second as " " separated tokens. If the second argument is too small -- the function recurses, and resizes the array as needed. The third argument is used to keep
  track of the recursion*/
char ** getArgs( char *input,  char **args, int ct) {
  int adj=(ct-1)*8;//if we recurse, this ensures correct indexes are used
  char *inputcpy=malloc(strlen(input));
  strcpy(inputcpy, input);

  /*Initialize indexes/Prepare for copying*/
  int i; 
  if(ct==1) {
    i=1; // this might throw off later adjusts
    args[0]=" "; //quick hack to ensure all args are used by exec()
  }
  else
    i=0;

  /**Actually do the copying now**/
  char *temp=strtok(NULL, " "); //What if later tokens are longer?
  args[adj+i++]=temp;

  while (temp != NULL && i<8) {
    temp=strtok(NULL, " ");
    args[adj+i++]=temp;
  }   

  /*If there are more args than we have room for*/
  if(i>=8){

    //is this allocation right?
    moreArgs = (char **) malloc((++ct)*8*sizeof( char *));

    /*Fill moreArgs with args*/
    int j;
    for (j=0; /*j<ct*8 && */args[j]!=NULL; j++) {
      moreArgs[j]=args[j];
    }   

    getArgs(inputcpy, moreArgs, (ct) ); //could probably move inc to malloc

    //free(args)?    
    if(ct>1)
      args=moreArgs;
  }
  /*Done with too many args problem*/


  return NULL;//(char **) args; //we don't want the global args though
}
```

Comment: `realloc()` is your friend...

Comment: I only skimmed the code, but `calloc` isn't technically guaranteed to initialize pointer types to `NULL` pointers. It initializes to all-bits-zero, which will mean numerically zero for integers, and `NULL` for platforms where the null pointer is numerically zero, but even if, at the C language level, zero is guaranteed to produce a `NULL` pointer, the machine-language level representation of a `NULL` pointer is not guaranteed to be "all-bits-zero." I don't know if your code relies on `calloc`-ed pointers being `NULL`, but if it does it's technically incorrect, if unlikely to break in practice.

Comment: @ChrisLutz wow, the things we have to deal with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not behaving the way you want it to is because you're passing `args` by value.

```
char ** getArgs( char *input,  char ***args, int ct);
```

This way, you can reassign `args`.

Edit: Make sure you free `args` before reassigning. Edit 2: That was too specific of me. Make sure you free *all* the objects that you dynamically allocated. There's quite a few that you have just left.

As a side note, you're calling `execvp` from the parent process, and calling `wait` from the child process. It should be the other way around. Also, you should avoid using `fork` with `execvp` and use `system` instead. You get the benefit that it's an atomic operation.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have a few follow ups (sorry, I'm just learning C). Ok so under that declaration, do I pass &args or do I have to declare args as char *** and then refer to it as *args otherwise?Also, after a whole semester of C, I only just found out about memory leaks. As far as I can tell, there are only three dynamically allocated objects: temp, args, and moreArgs. Is there anything else I should be free-ing?Finally, could you be clearer about system vs fork? If I don't fork, will execvp overwrite the parent program?

Comment: You would pass `&args`, and when accessing it in the function body, you would have to dereference it, e.g. `*args = moreArgs;`. The objects with allocated storage are `args`, `moreArgs` and `inputcpy`. `temp` isn't one of them. You can tell because they're initialized by calling `malloc()`/`calloc()`. I'm saying you should call `system()` instead of forking, exec'ing and wait'ing yourself. The benefit is that it's an atomic operation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up cutting my losses and rewriting with realloc(), but your posts have been really helpful!